# Missing "Plugin Store" navigation on Craft 3 admin section

Tags: craft3, plugins, menu

I am a newbie to CraftCMS and just installed my very first Craft Project on local Xampp. Everything looks good except the "**Plugin Store**" navigation menu is not showing up. Is there any trick or tweak to appear the default menu?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Craft 3](https://craftcms.com/blog/craft-3) for that. Looks like you are on version 2.7.4
The link provided gives information about new features in version 3, among them being the Plugin store.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot below, I've installed the latest version of craft.. :) 
https://prnt.sc/ma5b6m

Comment: You haven't, you're running version 2.7.4, which is at the bottom of your control panel. That's the latest version of Craft 2. The Craft 3.1 in your second screenshot is a news post, not the version you're running.

Craft 3 is a major update and therefore not available through the control panel. You can find information about updating to Craft 3 here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html

Comment: Thanks now I got this. xD But if I have installed Craft3 on my folder why it still showing Craft 2.7.4 version? :/