# Missing 'Plugin Store' tab in admin panel

Tags: craft2

I'm using Craft 2.7.9 and can't access the Plugin Store page. I've searched for fixes here but didn't find anything helpful.

I've tried to access it directly via http://localhost:8888/admin/plugin-store but I got an error:

> Page Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.

However, I'm not sure if the link is the same for Craft 2? That one I know from Craft 3.

Any ideas why is it missing? Need to install and test one plugin, tried to upload it manually to *plugins* folder but unfortunately that didn't work too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plugin Store is a feature introduced in Craft 3, so isn't available in previous versions.

See: [Missing Plugin Store Navigation on Craft 3 Admin Section](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29201/missing-plugin-store-navigation-on-craft-3-admin-section)
And: [Announcing Craft 3 Blog](https://craftcms.com/blog/craft-3)